# Npm accidentally deletes packages installed via 'ng add'

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular-schematics

tested on node 13.10.1

I'm installing some Angular Libraries+schematics (written by me) via `ng add` command. The libraries are added to the `package.json` **but not to the `package-lock.json`**.
When I try to serve my project, I got an error message for the libraries `peerDependecies` not satisfied.

1. I run `npm i <missingpackages...>`
2. I run `ng serve`

Then I got a new error, the Angular libraries I installed before are now vanished. Only their scope folder is left (@my-corp)

3. Then I re-run `npm i <libraries...>`,
4. `ng-serve`

And everything works fine (the libraries has been added to the `package-lock.json` too).
Can anyone explains me this weird behaviour?

Comment: Do you find your libraries in your package.json? Maybe they're not there?

Comment: @RubenSzekér package.json is fine, with all the packages I added before

Comment: Any answer to this would simply be a guess without a [mcve]

Comment: @Liam this issue is about npm/ng cli, how can I set an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The core of the issue is the lack of updates in `package-lock.json` after the `ng add <library>`command was run.

If you're the angular-library developer, to solve this its sufficient to execute inside the rule factory function this code:

```
export function ngAdd(options: ISchema): Rule {
  exec('npm i --package-lock-only'); // <- this code
  return (host: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {...};
}
```

If you're just a consumer, run this from the cli

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Hope this helps